# How to consume third party API with SSL Certifcate in UiPath

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator

I am trying to consume SSL configured API having https in UiPath Studio i am not finding any material regarding this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which API? And what you tried so far?

Comment: It is simple Rest API. I am calling Post method with access token.Url starts i.e https:hello/CallApi

Answer (score 0):

Https API is consumed at paid version of UiPath Studio. I was trying on community version.